# Get and Post doesnt respond after deploying to heroko

Tags: heroku

Good day ,

I am very new to node.js . deployed my application through heroko and yet all the get and post requests which works fine doesn't work .

i ran the console they provide and got the port from a console log which they assign to a random environment variable yet postman says no response .

this is my git repo
https://github.com/a7medsharaf/Bank_App

the problem is i don't know what to do next

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. What does "doesn't work" mean? Note that you should _not_ use the randomly-assigned port when trying to use your application. Use the regular HTTPS (443) or HTTP (80) ports. Heroku will route the request to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Edit :

After multiple trials and using the dotenv package turns out that heroko ignores your setting and you dont have to add a port to the API url . just use it without port and it worked !!